# Value error when predicting using my model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

here is my model, I was trying to predict a single element using my trained model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(length_max)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='gelu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(length_max))
```

```
word = "fo..st"
word = list(word)
word += [" "] * (length_max - len(word))
word = [[ord(char)/127.0 for char in chars] for chars in word]
word = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.asarray([np.asarray(list) for list in word]))
# the above is exactly I did previously when dealing my dataset, but the shape of any single element in my 
# dataset is [29], but the above here gives [29,1]

word = tf.reshape(word, (29))
# so I just reshaped here

word.shape
# to make sure the shape is [29]

model.predict(word)
# here I try to predict this single element using my trained model,
```

The last line gives the following Value Error

```
 ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_2' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_8" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_2' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float64)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

I also tried to predict a single element from my training set, but also get this error here.

I have tried specifying the dimensions of my layer as [length_max, 1] as some posts online suggested, but changing the dimensions all over the place incurs more error, and wouldn't even train the model. So, I gave up on changing the dimensions.

Comment: Put a comma in shape argument of Input layer: shape=(length_max,)

Comment: @MojtabaAbdiKhassevan Thanks. This is what I did before, but since the TensorShape is a single integer without comma, I removed the comma. I don't think this is making any difference though.